# validating an initially hidden form using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm validating an initially hidden form using jquery, but the form is submitted even though the fields are empty

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery("#name").validate({
        expression: "if (VAL) return true; else return false;",
        message: "* Please enter name"
    });

});
```

I'm doing this for ajax submition of the form ..

```
    $("#send").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
       var name = $('#name').val();
    $.ajax({

        // ajax submition 
       )};
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this... and use the `<form>` id instead for the validate function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#formid").validate({
        ignore:'',
        rules:{
            name:{
                required:true
            }
        },
        messages:{
            name:{
                required:'* Please enter name'
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I think you are using the newer version of jQuery validator plugin which ignores hidden elements by default.

In reply to your **updated** question you can just do this

```
$("#send").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $('#name').val();

   if(name.length > 0){ //if length is greater than 0 then only fire ajax else show the error
       $.ajax({

        // ajax submition 
       )};
   }else
       //show error
       alert('Name not found');
   }
}
```